# Hide scrollbar FullCalendar

Tags: html, css, fullcalendar

[image]

Hi everyone, I would like to hide this scrollbar that mess up with all the calendar. I've seen on another stackOverflow question to use  height:"auto" . It works but the size is too litle and we can't see all the events. If I try height:500; the scrollbar is still there.

I've tried to hide .fc-scroller but it's not working. How could i do ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for those who wonder. I've modified the js file. I change "lockOverFlow" and "applyOverflow" function by replacing the parameters overflow:x and overlow:y. I also changed the var e and n to apply the modifications. Like this :

```
applyOverflow:function(){this.scrollEl.css({"overflow-x":"hidden","overflow-y":"hidden"})},lockOverflow:function(t){var e="hidden",n="hidden";t=t||this.getScrollbarWidths(),"auto"
```